# NodeJS: Higher Order Function to Create Higher Order Function with Callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, undefined, higher-order-functions

As I have learned a little more about NodeJS and callbackHell I am trying to include more and more higher order functions in my project.
One idea I had was to make a function that creates other function in a manner that is suited to callback.

My approach looks like this:

```
function putFunctionInFunction(func, funcTwo) {
  const tempFunc = function (callback) {
    func(() => {
        funcTwo(callback);
    });
  };
  return tempFunc;
}
```

Following that my plan was to use this function to make a big-callback function out of an array of functions.

That functions looks like this:

```
function callbackFunctionArray(arr) {
let tempFunc = function (callback) {
    callback();
};
for (const func of arr) {
    tempFunc = putFunctionInFunction(tempFunc, func);
}
return tempFunc;
```

}

Sadly my first function does not work and I can not get my head around the reason why. It only produces 'undefined'-results. What I am guessing so far is that the function that I wanted to save in tempFunc is immediately evaluated and produces the 'undefined'-error.

My questions are this:

1. How can I realize my putFunctionInFunction-function without using other modules?
2. Is anything wrong with my second function - probably in the same area?
3. Is there a approach to combining functions that is better and/or different than mine?

Thanks for the help.

**UPDATE - QUESTION CLOSED:**
See my answer.

Comment: I'm not dismissing your efforts, but have you considered moving away from "regular" callbacks towards promises and `async/await`?

Comment: Your functions are looking fine - except maybe that they don't pass any argument values around, so they're not too useful. However they should work. Please show us how you did call `callbackFunctionArray` (with which  input) and how you called the resulting function, and where `undefined` was logged.

Comment: Thanks robertklep for the suggestion of async and co. I think I should use that in the future to avoid the chaos.

Also, thanks for the sanity check Bergi. I could not get my head around what was wrong, and as it turns out: just my input and not my functions.

Comment: If you no longer need an answer to your question, then you should either write your own answer (and accept it when you can) or you can just delete your question.  You shouldn't just leave it here the way it is now.

Comment: I will accept my answer, because I could not find a resource directly addressing a function like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All my functions work. I just spend many hours testing with the wrong input. An input that works would be the following:

```
const inputFunc1 = function (func2) {func2()};
const inputFunc2 = function (callback) { callback()};
putFunctionInFunction(inputFunc1,inputFunc2)(() => {console.log("hello")});
```

To avoid such problems it is probably a good alternative to use async/await and promises in the future for better clarity of code, as was suggested in the comments.

Anyways, I will leave this here, because I think it could be valuable for other people searching about higher order functions with this exact topic. I could not find any other resource about writing a function like this.